how to upload image in excel import in akeneo
I've set up a zip file for uploading an image, but when I check the product page, I'm getting the default image instead. I've reviewed all the documentation provided by Akeneo, but I haven't found a solution yet. Does anyone have any insights into how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
